# Windows Update MSRT KB890830 fails repeatedly on Windows 7 32-bit with error 8007000E

Tags: windows-7, windows-update

I have a number of machines that are failing to install the Feb 2019 and June 2019 MSRT KB890830 updates repeatedly. Other updates appear to be installing correctly.

I have done the following:

```
net stop wuauserv
net stop bits
ren %windir%\SoftwareDistribution softwaredistribution.bak
ren %systemroot%\system32\catroot2 catroot2.bak (this fails with Access Denied even in an admin cmd session)
net start wuauserv
net start bits
```

I have run the Windows Update Readiness Tool 
I have run the Windows
Update Troubleshooter
  I have run sfc /scannow 
I have restarted the PC
several times.

OS is Windows 7 SP1 32-bit

How can I get this to install correctly?

*After "hiding" the two problem updates, the May 2019 BK890830 update appeared and installed without a problem!

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to download it and install manually?

Comment: Yes I couldn’t tell if it even executed and it still shows up in the list.